# if statement in Linq query object creation

Tags: c#, linq

I am creating an object using Linq with the following code:

`Model.Select(m => new { id = m.ProcessId, parent = m.ParentProcessId, text = m.Name });`

However, I want to add in the following `if` statement for the `parent` property:

```
if (m.ParentProcessId == null)
    parent = "#";
else
    parent = m.ParentProcessId
```

Is there a way to do this inline with the Linq query? If not, how can this be done in a simple way?

Comment: [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) `parent = m.ParentProcessId == null?"#":m.ParentProcessId;`

Comment: You can write another method and call it, you can use action lambda expression, or just use https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: `parent = m.ParentProcessId ?? "#"` would be even more readable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as in [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

> The null-coalescing operator`??` returns the value of its left-hand operand if it isn't `null`; otherwise, it evaluates the right-hand operand and returns its result. The `??` operator doesn't evaluate its right-hand operand if the left-hand operand evaluates to non-null.

you can try the following

```
Model.Select(m => new { 
       id = m.ProcessId, 
       parent = m.ParentProcessId ?? "#",
       text = m.Name });
```